# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.Runtime

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, cucumber

I'm on a Java-Junit-Cucumber-Selenium project. When running the tests through Junit everything goes well, but I can't run via cucumber.
I tried with several versions.

POM xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>automacao</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <description>teste</description>

    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>4.2.6</cucumber.version>


    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central2</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Selenium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I encountered similar problems, but no solution solved my problem.
I have used the same code in other projects successfully.
Runner class:

```
package runners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/main/resources/features/Contas.feature",
        glue = "steps",
        tags ="@test1")

public class Runner {

}
```

Comment: can you try replacing  `<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>` with `<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>`?

Comment: You mixed two different `groupId` in the dependencies. Either change them all to `io.cucumber` or use older version `info.cukes`. Right now you have `io.cucumber` and `info.cukes` for gherkin

Comment: gherkin is a transitive dependency of cucumber-java and will be automatically pulled in. any specific reason to get this older version?

Answer (score 0):

Use Either the dependencies with info.cukes or  io.cucumber.Don't use it together. So Could you change the gherkin dependency with group id as "io.cucumber" as the rest of the cucumber dependencies you used are with group id "io.cucumber" or you could also use info.cukes for all of the cucumber dependencies 
This is the mvn repository link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin.Do refer this and modify the gherkin dependency with any of these stable version.
One of the stable version I found is the below one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope your issue will get solved.Thanks

Comment: Fiz isso, continuou com o mesmo problema. :/